# 3D Z-Y-X rotation of vector

Tags: 3d, matrix, rotation

I'm trying to rotate a vector in 3 dimensions by creating a rotation matrix from the world to the new rotation. I do the rotation by first rotating around the Z axis, then the Y axis and lastly the X axis using right hand notation.

The matrix I use can be found on wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles). It's located slightly below the middle of the page in the list of transformation matrices. I'm using the ZYX one:
[image]

I now create it with a Z rotation of +45 degrees, a Y rotation of +45 degrees and no X rotation. This gives me the following matrix:

```
[  0.5   -0.707 0.5   ]
[  0.5    0.707 0.5   ]
[ -0.707  0.0   0.707 ]
```

Now I multiply it by the following vector:

```
[ 10 ]
[  0 ]
[  0 ]
```

As can be seen it's a 10 unit long vector along the x-axis. I expect the rotated result to be around 6 in the x, y, and z field (with z being negative) as that gives a vector of roughly length 10. Ie the vector is rotated first exactly between the world x and y axis (the first z rotation) and then angled down from there another 45 degrees ending up exactly between the x-y plane and the negative z axis (the second y rotation). In my mind this means three equally long unit vectors representing this vector.

However, both my matrix class and all other programs give me this vector as result:

```
[  5    ]
[  5    ]
[ -7.07 ]
```

It seems correct as the length of it is 10 as expected. So the question is where am I wrong? I'm sure I'm making some stupid thought error somewhere obvious, because it sure doesn't have three equally long arms :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ZYX Euler angle rotation matrix is defined as

```
R_ZYX(dz, dy, dx) = R(Z, dz) * R(Y, dy) * R(X, dx)
```

There are two different ways of reading the order of the rotations: either from left to right or from right to left. When read from left to right the rotations are about the local axes of the coordinate frame, *as you are correctly doing*. It's only when read from *right to left* that the rotations are about a fixed coordinate frame.

Now to answer the question, let's compute the angle `dy` you *should* be rotating with if you want all coordinates of the rotated vector to have the same absolute value.

Let `r` be the length of `v` and let `a` be the absolute coordinate value. By Pythogoras, `a^2 + a^2 + a^2 = r^2`, hence `a = r / sqrt(3)`. The angle of the rotated vector relative to the XY plane is `dy = asin(a / r) = asin(1 / sqrt(3))`, which is about 35.3 degrees. This angle is different from the 45 degrees (or `asin(1 / sqrt(2))` in radians) that you are currently using.

A test (using Python and the [gameobjects](http://code.google.com/p/gameobjects/) library):

```
from gameobjects import *
from math import *
import random

V = vector3.Vector3
T = matrix44.Matrix44

def R_x(dx): return T.x_rotation(dx)
def R_y(dy): return T.y_rotation(dy)
def R_z(dz): return T.z_rotation(dz)

def fmt(v): return "(%.3f, %.3f, %.3f)" % (v[0], v[1], v[2])

dx = 0
dy = asin(1 / sqrt(3.0))
dz = pi / 4

v = V(10, 0, 0)

print "ZYX Euler angle transformations:"
print fmt((R_z(dz) * R_y(dy) * R_x(dx)).transform(v))
dy = pi / 4
print fmt((R_z(dz) * R_y(dy) * R_x(dx)).transform(v))
```

The output:

```
ZYX Euler angle transformations:
(5.774, 5.774, -5.774)
(5.000, 5.000, -7.071)
```

The last line for `dz = dy = pi / 4` shows that the program agrees with your Euler angle implementation.

Comment: Ok so say I wanted to first rotate my system in the x-y plane 45 degrees, and then draw a circle around the y axis in the newly rotated system (say with a radius of 10 units). I want it divided in 359 equally long segments (360 points calculated). As far as I can see using this matrix the segments will not be equally long in all parts of the circle if I let the y-rotation angle grow with 1 degree for each point. How would I proceed to do that? The important property for me is that the angle is proprtional to the calculated point so to speak.

Comment: Never mind, I understand how it works now. Everything is correct as I wrote it, it's just me not seeing how it comes together. The vector angled 45 degrees in the X-Y plane is described by two 5 unit length vectors along the x and y axis. This means that the length of the angled vector is sqrt(5^2 + 5^2) which is 7.07. Therefore we have a perfect 45 degree angled vector in all three dimensions if two of the arms are 5 in length and one is 7.07. As simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the second rotation is relative to the axis, not the vector. After rotating in the XY plane, imagine that whole plane twisting 45 degrees around the Y axis. This is not the same as twisting your rotated vector straight up (i.e. rotating around X=-Y) until it's at 45 degrees to the XY plane. Hard to explain, but I hope that helps :-)

*(Edit: got the axes the right way round)*